# Error sending and saving image in Ionic and Flask

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, ionic3

I am developing a project on Ionic. I have a server mounted on Flask and I would like to send images and treat them with this one.

I am currently doing the following:

```
this.uploadFile (this.canvas.nativeElement.toDataURL ("image / jpeg")); 

uploadFile(img) {
    let postParams = { file: img };

    this.http.setDataSerializer("json");
    this.http.post('http://46.101.150.118:5000/upload', postParams,
        {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    ).then(data => {
        this.drawCanvas(data);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

and in flask I receive it as "data" and not "files". Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try changing the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`.

Comment: give me an example please.